# PHP sends POST - how to process partial json response?

Tags: php, json, post, response

I've been a php programmer for years, but this is my first experience with json and dealing with responses from other servers, so please forgive my ignorance. Here's my situation:

1. MY form sends an image and some data to ANOTHER server
2. I have no control of the response, but it contains a known format
3. I need to do something with a portion of the repsponse, which is an incomplete json file, plus some text
4. how can I get the info I need from the response?  I just need to grab one variable and do something with it - I've got that handled as long as I can just GET the variable. The response looks like this:

   POST
   3d7164bd19712301847b6e42e4805581
   application/json
   Thu, 31 Oct 2013 07:02:11 GMT
   /targets{"target_id":"98a56b5364bc4b8cb3ea4c80740bf974","result_code":"TargetCreated","transaction_id":"9502e9edef2d4b3c8eaef8ae1b0ff41f"}

I need to get "target_id" and use it in another page.  Again, please forgive my newness, but as it is, I can't even find information on how to get ANYTHING and then go to another page once I've sent out the POST - Am I just so tired I've forgotten something?  I've been a programmer for 10 years!

Thanks for any help!

Comment: $json = json_decode($_POST[$payload_key]); And you can access your `target_id` with: $json->target_id

Comment: OK - I guess I understood that part.  Been awake for 30 hours, and I'm very tired - Here's my problem: I send the POST (standard form) to the outside server, it responds with what I posted above... For some reason, I can't remember the mechanism for doing ANYTHING with the response... I KNOW I sound stupid right now, but I have a short deadline, and I'm not thinking straight.  I'm happy to post my code if I need to.

Right now, I'm stuck after sending the form. looking at a page returned by the server to my browser, not knowing what to do to next.  just stuck in this one simple spot right now.

Comment: So you get the JSON as "content" and not in $_POST var? It's a POST request to your server with the JSON as "content" / "body"?

Comment: no headers. just raw data as content, yes

Comment: comes back exactly as formatted above